# AngularJS - parsing JSON feed with namespace

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, namespaces, angularjs-ng-repeat

New to angular, and it is awesome.

One thing I am having a brain fart on is parsing a JSON feed that contains namespaces:

Example from JSON feed:

```
"title": {
  "label": "Fuse"
},
"im:name": {
   "label": "John Doe"
},
"im:image": [ {
    "label": "70x70",
    "attributes": {
      "height": "55"
    }
  }, {
    "label": "80x80",
    "attributes": {
      "height": "60",
      "im:link": "www.google.com"
    }
  }, {
    "label": "90x90",
    "attributes": {
      "height": "170"m
      "im:link": "www.yahoo.com"
    }
}],
```

I can successfully parse items without namespaces fine like so:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in results.feed['entry']">
            title: {{item.title['label']}}
</p>
```

But cannot get the items with namespaces to display using:

```
            name: {{item.['im:name']['label']}}
OR
            name: {{item.['im-name']['label']}}
OR
            name: {{item.['im->name']['label']}}
```

Since being a newbie, I thought something like this would work:

```
<div xmlns:im="http://www.aol.com" id="im-app" im-app="im">
  <p ng-repeat="item in results.feed['entry']">
   …namespace code in here…
  </p> 
</div>
```

But that did not help.

Extra bonus question: What if a namespace contains attributes, that also contain namespaces?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!
Roc.

---

Although Craig answered the question,

This is also for reference for others:

If you want to target a specific key inside of an object set:

```
"im:image":[
  {
    "label":google",
    "attributes":{
      "height":"55"
    }
  },
  {
    "label":"yahoo",
    "attributes":{
      "height":"60"
    }
  },
  {
    "label":"aol",
    "attributes":{
      "height":"170"
  }
}

{{item['im:image'][2]['label']}}
```

Will get the 3rd key in that set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the dot after `item`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bonza_labs/Kc2uk/

You access the properties exactly the same way as straight javascript (because angular is basically eval()-ing the expression as javascript**). `item.['foo']` is not valid javascript. You are correct in using square-bracket notation as `my:name` is not valid for dot-notation.

valid:

```
item.foo
item['foo']
```

with non-standard property names:

```
item['foo:bar']
item['foo-bar']
```

and in your case:

```
{{item['im:name']['label']}}
```

** or close enough for understanding this solution

Comment: Hey Craig! Thanks! I accidently wrote that part of the code wrong. It was suppose to actually be `{{artist.im-artist['label']}}`, although what you wrote has helped me greatly and got it working.

Thanks for the heads up on the non-standard property names.

Comment: Hi Craig, since this deals with the same concept, I thought it would be unnecessary to create a new thread for this question. If you take a look here: [link](http://pastebin.com/HnnXdC8s), if a element contains keys that have the same name, how can I specifically target the 3rd key in line? I've tried `{{artist['im:image']['label(3)']}}` and `{{artist['im:image']['label'][3]}}`, but to no avail. – Roc 16 mins ago